# how to focus on another opened window in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If user open multi windows in different tabs, Is there any way that allow me to focus on another specific window in javascript or Jquery.

Comment: Not unless your script opened them, no.

Comment: I can open new tab with specific url using javascript, but I want to open that specific window if exist without open new tab again ?

Comment: Again, only if you opened the original tab yourself.  If you did then you just need to use the _name_ parameter.  If you specificy that then it will reuse the same tab or window next time you do the same.